# Indexing a large table to find distinct values in each columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing

The Table 'TestResult' is very large (20M+ rows), but not every Test, Student or ResultType is present in it.

I want to quickly get unique TestId, StudentId and ResultTypeId.
My current strategy is to have an index on each of the preceding columns in the following manner.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_TestResult_ResultTypeId] ON [dbo].[TestResult]
(
    [ResultTypeId] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
       SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I have one such index per column.

**Is this the correct way to do this or is there a better way to do this with only 1 index for all three columns ?**

I am using SqlServer 2016

[image: Schema]

Comment: Just to clarify, you want each unique `TestId`, `StudentId` and `ResultTypeId` independently, and not the unique combinaison of all 3?

Comment: @ESG - Correct.

Comment: then I believe creating those 3 indices is the right way to go about it

Answer (score 1):

As ESG has said, creating those three indices is the right way,
but if you have batch insert/delete/update on this table with large size of data,
you may have performance problems.